# Why is my delete button not working in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am having problems with implementing a delete button. It is supposed to remove an item from the RecyclerView if you click it. My layout file contains two TextViews and an ImageButton like so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_list_name" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/layout_list_delete" />
```

Here is my adapter class which manages the items and functions for the RecyclerView:

```
List<RecyclerViewListSchema> list;

public RecyclerViewListAdapter(List<RecyclerViewListSchema> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public static class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView date;
    ImageButton delete;

    public RecyclerViewViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_name);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_date);
        delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_delete);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list, viewGroup, false);
    RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.name.setText(list.get(position).name);
    viewHolder.date.setText(list.get(position).date);
    viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RecyclerViewListSchema item = list.get(position);
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

*Update:*
This is the exact location where my delete function works to remove the item:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder, final    int position) {
viewHolder.name.setText(list.get(position).name);
viewHolder.date.setText(list.get(position).date);
viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RecyclerViewListSchema item = list.get(position);
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
});
}
```

My RecyclerView populates all of the items from an SQLite database with the button next to it. I try to click on it but it doesn't do anything. What's going on in my code? Have I done something wrong? Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: also show the code where you are clicking on delete button

Comment: did you update your Sqlite database ? You should delete Item from your database too.

Comment: I have sorted out my problems. Apparently, the code I provided above actually works. For some reason, when I kept running my app on my phone, the app didn't update so I had to uninstall it and reinstall it. Thankyou all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onClick` to look like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    RecyclerViewListSchema item = list.get(position);
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't remove the item. What else can I try?

Comment: @GWX try putting Log.v() in onClick to see even it gets called

Comment: Nothing comes up in the Android Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on position during delete. Do this instead.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final RecyclerViewListSchema item = list.get(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(item.name);
    viewHolder.date.setText(item.date);
    viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos = list.indexOf(item);
            list.remove(pos);
            notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't remove the item.

Comment: print something in onClick method and make sure onClick is getting called.